# Как прикрутить папку к загрузке, google drive api, php?

Tags: php, api

может кто подскажет, нужна загрузка файлов на гугл диск с помощью сайта на api, собственно есть такой пример, где присутствует уже готовый код для этого, но файлы загружает в корень гугл диска, как можно изменить путь, чтобы загружало в определенную папку?

Собственно сам сайт с кодом - https://www.codexworld.com/upload-file-to-google-drive-using-php/

Кривовато получается сюда их скинуть, в общем интересует как правильно прикрутить папку, если можно с примером, заранее спасибо

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create есть параметр `parents` в котором передаются идентификаторы родителей. Возьмите официальную либу

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/folder#php тут еще примеры есть